# renderSectionFooter is not working

Tags: react-native

So I am using SectionList of react native to build a list. But somehow the renderSectionFooter is not working. However, renderSectionHeader is ok.

Here is my code:

```
<SectionList
 sections={[{data:self.state.lists}]}
 renderSectionFooter={() => {
        return(<Button title="Load More" onPress={()=>{
          console.log("renderSectionFooter","working");
        }}/>);
      }}
/>
```

I have been researching and google the whole days this seems to not a common bug to many people. I wonder what i done wrong.

Comment: What happens when you try to render `ListEmptyComponent`?

Comment: @HenrikR Nothing as well, it shows blank